# Craft 3 Plugin Controller - returnJson() replacement?

Tags: ajax, json

In Craft2, when making an ajax request to a plugin controller action, you would use the **returnJson()** method which is part of the **BaseController** class - which your plugin controllers extend.

This sets some headers, echo's the response and kills any further processing.

```
public function actionDoStuff() {

    $response = (object)[
        "message" => "Look at me! I'm JSON!"
    ];

    $this->returnJson($response);
}
```

In **Craft 3**/**Yii 2** I'm having trouble finding the equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't rtfm'ing hard enough. In the docs for [\yii\web\Controller](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-controller#asJson()-detail), which is what the **\craft\web\Controller** class extends (which is what your plugin controllers extend) there is a method **[asJson()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-controller#asJson()-detail)**.

```
return $this->asJson($response);
```